# get data by non primary key with java Dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I just started using DyanamoDB in AWS. I am using java to implement lambda functions. I want way to get the data from a table which is equivalent to below SQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM UserTable U WHERE 
U.email='sample@email.com' AND U.name LIKE 'Ste%';
```

where either one from email and name is not primary key.

But I still cannot find an straightforward way.
I could find that we have to have to know the primary key value to query the data. [AWS documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html) also not helping. Can someone please help me with an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can only query primary keys or indexes in DynamoDB.

You will either have to [add indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on those other fields, or perform an inefficient [scan operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) to find DynamoDB documents by other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to query dynamo db is by using primary key, if its really nessasary to query with non primary key consider using dynamo DB indexes you can create indexes on existing tables it will make your scan operation more efficient,

Indexes also allows you to query dynamoDB using secondry keys

To read more about indexes go to this link

[Indexes in dynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html)